# Unexpected rules format .rules when deploying firebase rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, rules

I'm trying to deploy my firebase rules running `firebase deploy --only database:rules`.
My `firebase.json` contains an attributes database:

```
"database": {
  "rules": "database.rules"
}
```

My file containing the rules is called `dabatase.rules`.
Running the deploy command, I get an error: `Error: Unexpected rules format .rules`.

Any ideas about what I did wrong ? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's appear that the `firebase.json` was wrong. I use Firestore Database. So, the attribute into the `firebase.json` has to be `firestore`

```
"firestore": {
  "rules": "database.rules"
}
```

Editing this, make everything work like a charm.